# Store whole dict in one element/cell of Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

is it possible to store a complex dict in one element of a Pandas DataFrame, please?
And later fill the whole column with similar structured dictionaries, please?

My Mini-Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create an example dict
dict={}
dict['key1']=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
dict['key2']=np.array([2])                     
dict['key3']='Mexico'

#create the pd DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(index=['0','1'], columns=['A','B'])
df
```

The following code

```
df[0,'A']=[dict]
df[1,'A']=[dict]
```

fails with
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)

In reality, my dict contains around 20 entries and I don't want to store each entry in a column for the same index. Or will this be the only way, please?
I thought I could create with Pandas some kind of small database.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.loc` to do that:

```
df.loc['0','A'] = [5,2,3]
df.loc['1','A'] = [dict]
```

Result:

```
                                                   A    B
0                                          [5, 2, 3]  NaN
1  [{'key1': [[1 2 3], [4 5 6]], 'key2': [2], 'ke...  NaN
```

You can also add new entries (rows):

```
df.loc['5','A'] = [{'test':'dummy'}]

                                                   A    B
0                                          [5, 2, 3]  NaN
1  [{'key1': [[1 2 3], [4 5 6]], 'key2': [2], 'ke...  NaN
5                                [{'test': 'dummy'}]  NaN
```